# Unable To Format String - Python

Tags: python, format

I'm unable to format this string, why is this?

```
def poem_description(publishing_date, author, title, original_work):
  poem_desc = "The poem {title} by {author} was originally published in {original_work} in {publishing_date}.".format(publishing_date, author, title, original_work)
  return poem_desc

my_beard_description = poem_description("1897", "Tauqeer", "Venice", "1992")

print(my_beard_description)
```

Comment: Can you make it clear? What is the error? What is the expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by "you are unable"?

Comment: The following message appears "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tauqeer Shoaib/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    my_beard_description = poem_description("1897", "Tauqeer", "Venice", "1992")
  File "C:/Users/Tauqeer Shoaib/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/main.py", line 2, in poem_description
    poem_desc = "The poem {title} by {author} was originally published in {original_work} in {publishing_date}.".format(publishing_date, author, title, original_work)
KeyError: 'title'"

Comment: See [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) (also called f-strings). `format` is passé.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curly brackets should be empty `{}`. You have typed variables in-between the curly brackets. Just remove them and you are good to go.

```
def poem_description(publishing_date, author, title, original_work):
  poem_desc = "The poem {} by {} was originally published in {} in {}.".format(title, author, original_work, publishing_date)
  return poem_desc

my_beard_description = poem_description("1897", "Tauqeer", "Venice", "1992")

print(my_beard_description)
```

Also, you can use formatted strings `poem_desc = f"The poem {title} by {author} was originally published in {original_work} in {publishing_date}."` The strings are prefixed with a `f` and then inside the string add variable in-between curly brackets.

Comment: So I should only add variables in curly brackets only if I add keywords in the argument and the string?

Comment: You should only add variables inside the curly braces if you are using formatted strings, string prefixed with a `f`. `string = f"Value of a - {a}"`

Comment: @t92 Just use f-strings, e.g.  `f'The poem {title} ...'`.  Drop the `.format` (Python 3.6+).

Answer (score 0):

It should either be like:

```
poem_desc = "The poem {} by {} was originally published in {} `in {}.".format(publishing_date, author, title, original_work)`
```

or like that:

```
poem_desc = f"The poem {title} by {author} was originally published in {original_work} in {publishing_date}."
```

Comment: Sure this alternative works, but It does not answer the question **why is this**.

Comment: When I add keywords in the argument and the string it works fine

Comment: @t92 well, you shouldn't add the arguments in it when string format is used. It needs arguments when f-string is used. String.format is based on the arguments order though.

Comment: I shouldn't add the arguments where?

Comment: @t92 you shouldn't add the arguments in it when string format is used. It needs arguments when f-string is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
def poem_description(publishing_date, author, title, original_work):
    poem_desc = "The poem {title} by {author} was originally published in {original_work} in {publishing_date}.".format(publishing_date=publishing_date, author=author, title=title, original_work=original_work)
    return poem_desc


my_beard_description = poem_description("1897", "Tauqeer", "Venice", "1992")

# Print the result
print(my_beard_description)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to maintain the curly bracket syntax you'll have to use `.format_map` instead of `.format` or use dictionary unpacking. Currently it expects a dictionary with keys `title`, `author` and all the others with are not present.

```
my_dict = {"title" : title, "author" : author} 
poem_desc = "The poem {title} by {author}".format_map(my_dict)
# or simply
poem_desc = "The poem {title} by {author}".format_map(**my_dict)
```